# How can I write a formula that will automatically take value from another subsheet in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, import, syntax, range, spreadsheet

For ex, we have 10 list of item with price which occupy 10 rows. and then in the total section we write something like this

```
=SUM(A1:A11)
```

So, it will give a total value of all 10 item's price. Now let's say after this formula, if I make any change, let's say I changed 5th row price to some diff amount, in that case google sheet is IMMEDIATELY amd automatically making change to our total value.

The similar behviour I want is. From same Google sheet with different SUB-SHEET, if I make any change, then that value I want it to reflect in my current subsheet in a particular position. Kind off automatically copy/paste to my current sheet, when I make change in my diff subsheet.

Is that possible?

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/168a1b2GAo-X4iw4-b18N9z7ROloToiUtWQUXnzp79zU/edit?usp=sharing

So from "Sheet A" I want to paste value to "Sheet B" everytime I make change in "Sheet A"

Comment: *possible* Sure. Easy? No. You'd have to write a script. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Ishika, You seem to have various misconceptions about Stackoverflow. Links are there to help you understand Stackoverflow and get along with the community better. Just because I commented, you can't assume I downvoted. Even if we assume I did, there's atleast one more downvote. You should [evaluate](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677) why  others are downvoting instead of complaining about the votes. Secondly, SO is a Q/A site for programmers. This is NOT a "help" community or forum for general users. A question is a contribution to the  programmer's community just like a answer is[1/2]

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/ **TL;Dr:** Do NOT ask a question because you want to know the answer. Ask a question because you want others to know the answer[2/2]

Comment: About the specifics of the question itself, I  assumed you wanted "copy paste" type like behavior. The answer below doesn't provide "copy paste" type behavior as the "pasted" value is not static. It'll change if the original "sub-sheet" value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
='Sheet A'!A13
```

[image]

if sub sheet name does not contain space you can omit single quotes `'`:

```
=SheetA!A13
```

the same way you can use:

```
=SUM('Sheet A'!A2:A12)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working as expected. Also one last thing, is it possible from 1 sheet [not subsheet] to another sheet from same Google account? [yes, consider having owner access in both the sheet]

Comment: @IshikaSingh yes, possible. you would need to use `=IMPORTRANGE("url-of-sheet-here"; "Sheet A!A13")`